# Using PHP to create HTML file

Tags: php, html

I have a index.php file that loads server details with (for example)

```
$ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$browser    = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

at the end of the script an jpg will be displayed.

Now I would like the index.php file to create a single html file with a table format in it where the data gets imported / written to from the index.php.

So in the end I would like to open log.html and then see all the index.php submits in a html table.

Please help.

I already tried:

```
$f=fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($f,$data."\r\r\n");
fclose($f);
```

the current situation is that the code I wrote, the output goes to the log.txt file as plain text. Every submit is added as newline.

Sorry for inconvenience, below full code:

```
    <html>
    <?php
    $file       = "log.txt";
    $date       = date("d-m-y");
    $time       = date("H:i:s");
    $ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $browser    = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $user       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
    $remote_usr = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'];
    $host       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
    $method     = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    function getRealIpAddr()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
        {
          $ip1=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
          $ip1=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
          $ip1=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip1;
    }
    $ip2 = getRealIpAddr();

    $data = "Date: ".$date." ,Time: ".$time.",User:".$user.", RM user: ".$remote_usr.", Host:".$host.",IP: ".$ip.", IP2: ".$ip2.", Browser: ".$browser;

    $f=fopen($file, 'a');
    fwrite($f,$data."\r\r\n");
    fclose($f);
    ?>



    <img src="img.JPG">
    <!--http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php -->
    </body>
    </html>



----------------
i did a lot of googling, i solved my problem with the following: gen.php


<?php 

    $lines = file("log.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $data = array_map(function($v){
        list($username, $score, $user, $user_rm, $host, $ip, $ip2, $browser) = explode("+", $v);
        return [
        "Date" => $username, 
        "Time" => $score, 
        "User" => $user, 
        "RM user" => $user_rm,
        "Host" => $host,
        "IP" => $ip,
        "IP2" => $ip2,
        "Browser" => $browser
        ];
    }, $lines);

/*    usort($data, function($a, $b){
        if($a["score"] == $b["score"])
            return 0;
        return $a["score"] > $b["score"] ? 1 : -1;
    });*/

?>

<table width="100%" border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:grey;"><b>Date</b></td>
        <td style="background-color:grey;"><b>Time</b></td>
        <td style="background-color:grey;"><b>User</b></td>
        <td style="background-color:grey;"><b>RM User</b></td>
        <td style="background-color:grey;"><b>Host</b></td>
        <td style="background-color:grey;"><b>IP</b></td>
        <td style="background-color:grey;"><b>IP2</b></td>
        <td style="background-color:grey;"><b>Browser</b></td>

    </tr>
<?php foreach($data as $user){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td height="100%"><?php echo $user["Date"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user["Time"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user["User"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user["RM user"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user["Host"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user["IP"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user["IP2"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user["Browser"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

and this page: index.php

```
<html>
<?php
$file       = "log.txt";
$date       = date("d-m-y");
$time       = date("H:i:s");
$ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$browser    = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$user       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
$remote_usr = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'];
$host       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
$method     = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip1=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip1=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip1=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip1;
}
$ip2 = getRealIpAddr();

$data = "Date: ".$date." + Time: ".$time."+ User:".$user."+ RM user: ".$remote_usr."+ Host:".$host."+ IP: ".$ip."+ IP2: ".$ip2."+ Browser: ".$browser;

$f=fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($f,$data."\r\r\n");
fclose($f);
?>
<img src="img.JPG">
<!--http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the PHP functions `fopen` and `fwrite`.

Comment: if you are going to write to a .txt file it will be written as plain text. If you would like it to be html text write to .html file. Really hard to understand what your output you like. Can you better describe or show the output you want?

Comment: Well, you've got a couple possible solutions.  You could either create another PHP script that reads and parses your log text file and outputs HTML, or you could implement a database solution where instead of writing to a text file, you write to the database, and then create a PHP script that reads the records from the database and outputs the result as HTML.

Comment: i clearly understand that. I would like to generate a html table with the content in it. that is the problem @pal4life

Comment: @PatrickQ Thank you, i will 'google' for the php script to create html file table with input from log.txt file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal decision in such case would be NOT *"to create a single html file"* each time when `index.php` get to run. You should create base static structure of your `html` file beforehand with separation on templates. All you need is to append is new table row `<tr>` with filled cells `<td>`.
Create the two new `html` files on the same level as your current script (though I would better place them into separate folder).
The first file, lets say `base.html`, should contain the following markup:
*base.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>oop</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>RM user</th>
                <th>Host</th>
                <th>IP</th>
                <th>IP2</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
            </tr>
```

The second file, lets say `bottom.html`, will be the 'closing' fragment of intended html file and should contain the following markup:
*bottom.html:*

```
       </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then rename the file in your `index.php` like this:

```
$file = "log.html";
```

Replace this code:

```
$ip2 = getRealIpAddr();

$data = "Date: ".$date." ,Time: ".$time.",User:".$user.", RM user: ".$remote_usr.", Host:".$host.",IP: ".$ip.", IP2: ".$ip2.", Browser: ".$browser;

$f=fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($f,$data."\r\r\n");
fclose($f);
```

with the following:

```
$ip2 = getRealIpAddr();

$data = "<tr><td>".$date."</td><td>".$time."</td><td>".$user."</td><td> ".$remote_usr."</td><td>".$host."</td><td>".$ip."</td><td>".$ip2."</td><td> ".$browser."</td></tr>";

file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);
 ...

// To output the final html file use:
   readfile('base.html');
   readfile('log.html');
   readfile('bottom.html');
```

That's all! )

Comment: how can i ensure there are not double ip adresses displayed in the table? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 separate files. (My files are simplified, to demonstrate the strategy.

**results.php**

```
<html>
    <title>The results</title>
    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>IP Address</td>
            <td>Browser</td>
        </tr>
            <?php include("contents.incl");
        <table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, as your main script is called, you append html code to  contents.incl

```
$f=fopen($file, 'a');

$rowMarkup = '<tr>';
$rowMarkup .= '    <td>' . $ip . '</td>';
$rowMarkup .= '    <td>' . $browser . '</td>';
$rowMarkup = '</tr>';

fwrite($f,$rowMarkup."\r\r\n");

fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "";
if (filesize($file)==0) {
    $data .= "<html><body><table>";
}
$data .= "<tr><td>Date: ".$date."</td><td>Time: ".$time."</td><td>User:".$user."</td><td>RM user: ".$remote_usr."</td><td>Host:".$host."</td><td>IP: ".$ip."</td><td>IP2: ".$ip2."</td><td>Browser: ".$browser."</td></tr>";
```